# Error al ejecutar un archivo makefile

Tags: makefile

tengo un problema cuando quiero ejecutar un archivo Makefile, despues de instalar el gnu de windows, se compilo y ejcuto, pero daba un error en la linea de Shell bin/bash, lo cual corregí copiando todo el directorio de la instalación de la GNU make file y funcionó pero me dice que Makefile no tiene nada que hacer, este es el código de un archivo Makefile:

```
# (c) 2017. All rights reserved.
# Makefile that installs and runs the project.

ENV := NODE_ENV=dev
SRC_DIR:= src
WORK_DIR:= work

SRC_SCSS:= $(SRC_DIR)/css/style.scss
ENTRY_JS = $(SRC_DIR)/js/index.js
SRC_JS:= $(SRC_DIR)/js/*.js webserver.js .eslintrc.json

JS_TARGET:= $(WORK_DIR)/bundle.js
JS_MAP:= $(WORK_DIR)/map.js
JS_LIB_TARGET:= $(WORK_DIR)/bundle-lib.js
CSS_TARGET:= $(WORK_DIR)/bundle.css

# Get ES6 + React compilation + type checking
BABELIFY_PACKAGES := babel-core babelify babel-preset-react babel-preset-env babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
BROWSERIFY_PACKAGES := browserify envify uglify-js uglifyify
ESLINT_PACKAGES := eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-node
REACT_PACKAGES := react react-dom
NPM_INSTALL := npm install --save-dev $(BABELIFY_PACKAGES) $(BROWSERIFY_PACKAGES) $(ESLINT_PACKAGES) $(REACT_PACKAGES)

ESLINT := node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
ESLINT_FLAGS := --fix

BROWSERIFY := $(ENV) node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js
BABELIFY := babelify --presets [ env react ] --plugins [ transform-class-properties ]
BROWSERIFY_FLAGS := -d -t [ $(BABELIFY) ]
#BROWSERIFY_FLAGS := -d -t [ $(BABELIFY) ] -g [ envify --$(ENV) ] -g uglifyify


UGLIFY := node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs --compress --mangle

SHELL := bin/bash
PWD := $(shell pwd)

# Default; builds
all: prep $(JS_TARGET) $(CSS_TARGET)

# Builds + runs server
serve: all
    node webserver

clean:
    rm -rf $(WORK_DIR)

.PHONY: clean all serve

install:
    $(NPM_INSTALL)

prep: $(WORK_DIR) # make sure build directories are present
$(WORK_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(JS_TARGET): $(ENTRY_JS) $(SRC_JS)
    $(ESLINT) $^ $(ESLINT_FLAGS)
#   $(BROWSERIFY) $< $(BROWSERIFY_FLAGS) | $(UGLIFY) > $@
    $(BROWSERIFY) $< $(BROWSERIFY_FLAGS) > $@

$(CSS_TARGET): $(SRC_SCSS)
    cat $^ >& $@
```

al ejecutarlo, no me da ningún error pero no hace nada. Me muestra un mensaje Makefile no tiene nada que hacer. Que podría cambiarle

Comment: Eso es lo esperado. Si no hay ningún cambio en tus archivos `.js`, `make` **no hace nada**. Para forzar a que vuelva a *reconstruir* todo, puedes hacer `make clean`, que borrará todo lo generado por `make`.